# Open new windows form window, closes immediately

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to open a new windows form, however it seem to close immediately every time.
it works if i use ShowDialog() instead of Show(), but that is not my intention.

```
class Forms
{
    Main mainForm;
    Thread mainThread;

    public Forms()
    {

    }
    private void ThreadProc()
    {
        try
        {
            mainForm = new Main();
            mainForm.Show();

        }
        catch {  }
    }
    public void startMain()
    {
        mainThread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(ThreadProc));
        mainThread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
        mainThread.Start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is your mainThread does not run any message loop (that is responsible to react to all the GUI-related messages like resizing, button clicks, etc...), and so after calling `mainForm.Show()` the thread finishes.
In fact winforms applications usually start like this:

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

where, as you can see in the [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.application.run%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), `Application.Run` starts a standard message loop in the current thread and shows the form.

If you use `ShowDialog()` it works because modal forms run their own message loop internally.

I don't know what you are trying to accomplish but ShowDialog might be the easiest solution; in case you don't like it just replace your `mainForm.Show` with `Application.Run(mainForm)` and it should work.

Answer (score 4):

You would need to use Application.Run to start the application message loop, otherwise the program would act like a console app and close once its code has finished executing.

Add `using System.Windows.Forms;` to the top of the class.

Then change `mainForm.Show();` to `Application.Run(mainForm);` inside ThreadProc.

Answer (score 2):

You should [use](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms157902.aspx):

```
Application.Run(new MainForm());
```

> Begins running a standard application message loop on the current
>   thread, and makes the specified form visible.